# Laravel 5 Redirect::away never redirects

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am working with PayPal sdk, i have a problem, the page never redirects to PayPal. 
 If I `dd($redirect_url)` inside the `if(isset($redirect_url))` statement, it shows me the string to the PayPal sandbox website. If I paste that link into a separate window it goes to the PayPal sandbox site with them items i added to my carts. 
 For some reason it will not redirect when i do return `Redirect::away($redirect_url);` 
 Here is the relevant code.

```
try {
        $payment->create($this->_api_context);
    } 

    catch (\Paypal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
            echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
            $err_data = json_decode($ex->getData(), true);
            exit;
        } else {
            die('Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient');
        }
    }

    foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
            $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
            break;
        }
    }


    // add payment ID to session
    Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());

    if(isset($redirect_url)) {
        // redirect to paypal

       return Redirect::away($redirect_url);

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're definitely hitting that if statement?

Comment: Ok I just tried header("Location: ".$redirect_url); and that worked just fine. Something has to be wrong with the laravel Redirect.

Comment: Yes I am sure I am getting inside the if statement, I did a dd($redirect_url) inside of the if statement, and it output the link itself.

Comment: Have you specified to 'use Redirect' inside of the controller? You need to import the facade.

Comment: Yes, I have Use Redirect at the top. I have also tried the helper function return redirect()->away($redirect_url). Weird thing is that the favico changes to the paypal logo, but the page never changes.

Comment: I have the same problem. But header() is not working

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: why not using `redirect helper`? instead of `return Redirect::away($redirect_url)` try `return redirect($redirect_url)`.